# Example cx_oracle does not work, python3.3

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

When I execute my file **test_cx_oracle.py** with a python 3.3 interpreter it errors with the following output.

```
**File "test_cx_oracle.py", line 3  
**print con.version"**
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**
```

The contents of this file are as follows,

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('system/diamondmine@127.0.0.1/XE')
print con.version
con.close()
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 2):

In python 3.x the the `print` *statement* has been replaced by a `print` *function*.

Since functions *must* be called by having a set of trailing `()` (which contain arguments to the function), you must add them to `print` calls in python 3.x. In the case of the `print` function the usual syntax is just to pass the value you wish to be printed to the `print` function directly.

With that in mind, changing line 3 to the following should correct your error.

```
print(con.version)
```